# MySQL Copy Raw Data from One Database to Another only where key raw value match

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Hi there I have to alter more than 300 data in mysql and i think if i do individual its time...

So i need your help to easy my problem. Thanks in advance,

Database - A 
ATable-1
 - raw-name
 - raw-key(this should be identifier identifier)
   - Key_a
   - Key_b
   - Key_c
   - Key_b
   - Key_b
 - raw-school(i want to copy data here)

Database - B
BTable-1
- raw-school(i want to copy data from this raw)

My Quest is I have two Database A and B, I want copy Data from Database B to Database A

But I want Only in case of Match Atable1 > raw-Key has value > Key_b

[image]

Comment: Both databases on same server?

Comment: yes salmon same server

Comment: If on the same server I'm not clear what your problem is - this looks like a simple update using fully qualified table names ie dbname.tablename